# Native javascript задача

Tags: javascript, native

Есть такая вот задача, вроде простая, но так как я новичок не могу понять как её решить?

```
// Нужно написать функцию get. На вход функция принимает объект и путь до поля объекта.

var obj = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c: 'd' 
    },
    e: 'f'
  }
};

get(obj, 'a.b');   // Должно получится так: { c : 'd' }
get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // Должно получится так: 'd'
get(obj, 'a.e');   // Должно получится так: 'f
```

Comment: Вы что-нибудь пробовали сделать? Подсказка: имеется в виду, что Вы будете использовать квадратно-скобочное обращение к свойствам объектов.

Comment: А что, собственно, мешает просто обращаться к свойствам объекта как ```obj.a.b``` или ```obj.a.b.c```?

Comment: @gregzakharov Все что угодно. Например, путь к свойству задается строкой.

Comment: @Grundy, ну ты шустрый. А я другой дубликат нашёл.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а какой? Я помню что-то еще было, но не нашлось :)

Comment: @Grundy, в список дубликатов загляни ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, я про него и думал, но не нашел :-)